# Suppress "Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6"

Tags: powershell, console

I don't mind a bit of Microsoft marketing, but this is annoying when I just want a clean PowerShell prompt. Has anyone found a way of suppressing just the `Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6` on opening PowerShell, *without* removing the basic copyright message `Windows PowerShell, Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.`? I've googled around a lot but found no answer (I know there is a way to suppress *everything*, but I just want rid of that pscore6 advert only).

Comment: I just open a the window then just type `cls` or `Clear-Host` to remove everything. Then I get a clean shell with only `PS C:\Users\user>`. Seems like too much effort to remove the advert when I can just clear the window.

Comment: You could stick `cls` or `Clear-Host` in your $PROFILE, but that could be annoying as well if you start it up from a CMD prompt and still want to see what was displayed.  The flash is a bit annoying even when starting up a Powershell prompt directly.

Comment: I know that I can do that, and thanks for that, but I was just hoping to open PowerShell without having to do that. i.e. leave the copyright logo like normal, but just disable the annoying Microsoft marketing. I completely understand what you mean about it maybe seeming like too much effort, but thought / hoped that maybe someone here had found the magic trick to make that advert go away!

Comment: Interestingly, I guess that when PS Core 7 is fully released, they will update the advert to say `pscore7` so hopefully there is some way to tweak this unless they've embedded it inside the powershell.exe or something like that. :-(

Comment: The message is super annoying because I did try the "new cross-platform PowerShell" and I didn't like it one bit. In fact, I hated it very much and every time see this message I am reminded of how much I dislike it and I associate that hatred with Microsofts lack of taste. At least if windows somehow noted I installed it, tried it and thought very little of it and stopped spamming. I went with Eugene Kopichs answer: I'd rather loose the whole start message than continue to see the Microsoft spam.

Answer (score 41):

Since [Windows Terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal) 1.0 is released, you can use it instead.
In settings add a flag `-NoLogo` as shown below:

```
    "list": [
  {
    // Make changes here to the powershell.exe profile.
    "guid": "{61c54bd-c2c6-5271-96e7-009a87ff44bf}",
    "name": "Windows PowerShell",
    "commandline": "powershell.exe -NoLogo",
    "hidden": false
  },
```

Comment: This removes also the text "Windows PowerShell, Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved."

Comment: if you don't mind getting rid of the copyright the whole command is `Powershell.exe -NoLogo` (for users who don't know how to add a flag)

Comment: Can you please say, where in settings we should add flag?

Comment: It says unknown configuration settings.

Comment: For anyone else having trouble finding the settings in the first place, you have to click the small downwards arrow to the right of the "new tab" button.

Comment: Down arrow as AMTK said, select shell of choice under Profiles in left menu.  From there you can add edit the info either by editing within the fields input fields in the main windows (Command Line in this case)  or by clicking the "Open JSON file" option at the bottom of the left menu (that is the view from original answer.

Comment: Since 1.7 Windows Terminal has UI for settings which makes it easier to edit. Before that, it was only through editing a JSON file.

Answer (score 22):

You can get rid of the copyright banner by starting powershell from running this in cmd:

```
Powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoExit
```

`-NoExit` is not necessary as @Albin said, and you could create a desktop shortcut/batch file from it.

Comment: thanks for the post! Added `-NoLogo -NoExit` to my PS shortcut on the Taskbar, and it worked like magic! 1. Pin PS to taskbar
2. Right-click the icon, right-click `Windows Powershell`, click `Properties`
3. Add `-NoLogo -NoExit`at the end of `Target`

Comment: Important to note: `-NoExit` isn't necessary and `-NoLogo` gets rid of the copyright message as well (the OP what to keep the copyright message intact)

Comment: This also worked for me in VS Code, by adding `"args": ["-NoLogo"]` to the powershell entry in settings.json

Answer (score 15):

This message is part of the resource string embedded in `Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost` in the `ManagedEntranceStrings.resources` resource. The full message is

> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

This is one string, not two, and there is no logic for picking a different banner.

Because the string is read as a resource, in theory you could create a new resource assembly and put it in `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\en-US`. In practice you can't (even if you'd be willing to put new files in a system directory), because the main assembly is strong-named and installed in the GAC, which means you can't produce a satellite assembly that will load since you don't have the private key required for signing. It does, however, work -- I verified this by building such an assembly with delayed signing, but obviously that's not really a workable idea on a production system.

Comment: Fascinating. Thanks for that Jeroen. So Microsoft have decided to quite deeply embed this advert. Shame. And when PS 7 goes full release, they will make an update change this to advertise PS 7. Can I live with it? Sure, but I'm not really a big fan of blatant advertising ... shame there is no easy way to purge this pointless Microsoft advertising. Thanks!

Comment: PS 6 isn't halfway done yet; when it is, I suspect this ad will either get removed, changed to just `pscore`, or the `pscore6` link will actually forward to PS 7, because MS has essentially stopped major development on the "classic" PowerShells for the moment (pre-Core) and they'd like us all to migrate. It doesn't really make sense to sink effort into updating classic PS *just* for this string (unless it comes along with a security patch or something).

Comment: Indeed, yes, PS 5.1 is *end of life* of course, and PS 7 is ultimately the future (hopefully they build it out to give us all the features of 5.1 as soon as possible). I don't object to the direction that MS is taking things (in fact, it's pretty exciting in many ways). That pscore6 advert will be a bit redundant when PS Core 7 is out, but yeah, they can't leave it saying pscore6 when pscore7 is out for a year or more, that'll look a bit silly, but I guess they've got some kind of path, mothball 5.1 when 7 can cover everything maybe but that would be kind of drastic...

Answer (score 7):

Replace command line argument in settings.json with this:

```
"commandline": "powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoExit -Command Write-Host Windows PowerShell`nCopyright `(C`) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.`n",
```

[image: powershell]

It disables original text, and writes what we need instead.
If you want to write something else, use `` `n `` for new lines, and don't forget to add `` ` `` for escaping reserved symbols, like parentheses.

Different language example:

```
"commandline": "powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoExit -Command Write-Host Windows PowerShell`n`(C`) Корпорация Майкрософт `(Microsoft Corporation`). Все права защищены.`n",
```

Comment: This approach is perfect for Windows Terminal. Although it's not generic at the moment, hopefully Windows Terminal will become the default PowerShell terminal when Windows 11 is released.

Comment: Where is `settings.json` located?

Comment: @ChrisCrossCrash That's honestly a bit of "old" information.  While you can still change it through `settings.json`, Microsoft has now added the ability to change most settings directly through the UI.  Just make the change to the "Command Line" setting for the PowerShell profile.  If you *do* want to see `settings.json`, it can be opened through a link at the bottom-left of the Settings screen - "Open JSON file".

Answer (score 2):

### Suppressing messages in IntelliJ IDEA (i.e. WebStorm).

Had the same messages in the terminal windows of my WebStorm.
You can suppress these messages by adding the `-NoLogo` flag to the Shell Path for the Terminal Emulator.

1. Go to the settings for configuring [the Terminal Emulator](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/terminal-emulator.html#configure-the-terminal-emulator) by clicking:
   `File menu -> Settings -> Tools -> Terminal.`
2. Click to confirm editing these settings if needed and then change the Shell path accordingly to: 
   `powershell.exe -NoLogo`

When you next time start your IntelliJ IDEA the terminal windows will be clean.

Answer (score -10):

This message means "you are using the old version of powershell". You must update it with commands and software.
When I updated powershell, this message never came again.

Comment: Unfortunately, even on the latest version of PowerShell, you get junk. When I install 7, I also get 

`https://aka.ms/powershell
Type 'help' to get help.`

Would be nice if Microsoft gave us the option to get rid of the junk. It's hard to take it seriously when they are pushing their ads at us that we don't need to see :-(

Comment: Powershell 5.1 is the still corporate standard.  It comes with Windows Server and it's the basis of a lot of in-house scripts.  The later versions have just a few nice but not that compelling features.  That would be weighed against the costs and risks of upgrading all Windows servers and checking code.  If it ain't broke...