# Hide: Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

Tags: powershell

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\Users\manar>
```

Every time I open a PowerShell windows I get this message.
Does anyone have an idea on how to hide this recommendation? Thanks!

Comment: Launch with `-NoLogo`: `powershell.exe -NoExit -NoLogo`

Comment: OK, but is there a way to start it like this from the taskbar. If you answer to me post an answer so I can accept it and vote it up. - This answer is good!!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Suppress "Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59671389/suppress-try-the-new-cross-platform-powershell-https-aka-ms-pscore6)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can suppress the entire top banner with the [`-NoLogo` command line switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe?view=powershell-5.1#-nologo).

To make this the default when launching from the taskbar in Windows 10:

- Right-click the pinned Windows PowerShell item
- Right-click "Windows PowerShell" -> Select Properties
- Add `-NoLogo` to the `Target` value:

[image]